# android title with rainbow effect

Tags: android, title, effect

I need to add a rainbow effect on the title like

[image: this] image.

Any ideas?

I found some answers for textView, but nothing for the title from the toolbar

Comment: You can use an advice posted here https://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-textview/#/38 to create your custom RainbowSpan and then use SpannableString as your title.

Comment: thx, i used your advice in combination with Arsen Sench answer and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static TextView getToolbarTitleView(ActionBarActivity activity, Toolbar toolbar){
    ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
    CharSequence actionbarTitle = null;
    if(actionBar != null)
        actionbarTitle = actionBar.getTitle();
    actionbarTitle = TextUtils.isEmpty(actionbarTitle) ? toolbar.getTitle() : actionbarTitle;
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(actionbarTitle)) return null;
    // can't find if title not set
    for(int i= 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++){
        View v = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
        if(v != null && v instanceof TextView){
            TextView t = (TextView) v;
            CharSequence title = t.getText();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && actionbarTitle.equals(title) && t.getId() == View.NO_ID){
                //Toolbar does not assign id to views with layout params SYSTEM, hence getId() == View.NO_ID
                //in same manner subtitle TextView can be obtained.
                return t;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}



 TextView tv= getToolBarTitleView(activity,toolbar);
 if(tv!=null){
    Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 20,
    new int[]{Color.YOURCOLOR,Color.YOURCOLOR},
    new float[]{0, 1}, TileMode.CLAMP);
    tv.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
 }
 else{
  Log.e("MYPROJECT","No textview in toolbar . . . ");
 }
```

Comment: thx, i used your getToolbarTitleView() in combination with the github link from the first comment and it worked :)

Comment: happy to help you :)